# Java Swing: problems with width

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, preferredsize

I have problems with understanding the behavior of my application. I want to create a simple window (*1000x700px*), divided into two parts (*250px* and *750px* width respectively). I tried the following code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Example extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Example()
    {
        this.setSize(1000, 700);
        this.setTitle("Example");
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));

        JPanel navigation_panel_wrap = new JPanel();
        JPanel content_panel_wrap = new JPanel();
        navigation_panel_wrap.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 700));
        content_panel_wrap.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 700));
        content_panel_wrap.setBackground(Color.green);
        navigation_panel_wrap.setBackground(Color.red);
        this.getContentPane().add(navigation_panel_wrap);
        this.getContentPane().add(content_panel_wrap);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Example example = new Example();
        example.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

As you can see I manually set layout manager for `JFrame` (`FlowLayout` instead of `BorderLayout` with **zero horizontal and vertical gaps**). Of course, I can just use `BorderLayout` and than use `add()` method with `BorderLayout.EAST` and  `BorderLayout.WEST` parameters, but I want to understand what's wrong with `FlowLayout`. 
When I run my application, I get the following (no green `JPanel`):  [image]

If I decrease width of, for example, `content_panel_wrap` and make it *744px* instead of *750px*, everything works correctly.
[image]
So the question is - what are these strange 6 pixels? I'm not sure this value is constant for all operating systems, so I want to understand its origin.

Comment: See this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for your codes problem (+1 to @Reimeus) calling `pack()` is the solution.
as per docs:

> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts
>   of its subcomponents. If the window and/or its owner are not yet
>   displayable, both are made displayable before calculating the
>   preferred size. The Window will be validated after the preferredSize
>   is calculated.

**Tips:**

- Dont extend `JFrame` unnecessarily.
- Use [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) when creating and changing UI components:

  ```
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // create UI components etc here
      }
    });
  ```
- Dont call `setPreferredSize()` rather override `getPrefferedSize()` of component.
- Dont call `setSize(...)` on `JFrame` rather call `JFrame#pack()` before setting it visible.
- Dont forget to call `JFrame#defaultCloseOperation(..)` or your initial/EDT thread will not be terminated when `JFrame` is closed.

Here is an example combining my advice and your code:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Example {

    private final JFrame frame;

    public Example() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//app exited when frame closes
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));

        JPanel navigation_panel_wrap = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(250, 700);
            }
        };
        JPanel content_panel_wrap = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(750, 700);
            }
        };

        content_panel_wrap.setBackground(Color.green);
        navigation_panel_wrap.setBackground(Color.red);

        frame.add(navigation_panel_wrap);
        frame.add(content_panel_wrap);
        //pack frame (size components to preferred size)
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);//make frame visible
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such detailed answer!
Everything is clear except two things:
1. _Dont extend JFrame unnecessarily._
I shouldn't extend all Swing classes like JLabel, JPanel etc. or just JFrame? And what is the reason of doing this? 
2. What is the advantage of overriding getPrefferedSize() over using setPreferredSize()?

Comment: @user1600356 +1 its a pleasure. As for `JFrame` extending question : 1)you only extend classes to add functionality 2) once you extends `JFrame` you cant extend another class which you may **ACTUALLY** need to. As for your question : *What is the advantage of overriding getPrefferedSize() over using setPreferredSize()?* see this link: [Should I avoid the use of set\[Preferred|Maximum|Minimum\]Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/1133011)

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing wrong with `FlowLayout` but you will need to call `pack()` for all components to be sized.